# Permission Dialog not Showing Up Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow)

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, smsmanager

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            Cursor temp = db.rawQuery("Select name from profile;", null);
            temp.moveToFirst();
            Toast.makeText(TrustedContacts.this, ""+c.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            (SmsManager.getDefault()).sendTextMessage("0"+c.getString(2), null, "Automated SMS by Medical Alert App by " + temp.getString(0), null, null);
            Toast.makeText(TrustedContacts.this, "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(TrustedContacts.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
```

Here is the Code for sending SMS through SMS Manager on Permission Granted, but the Permission Dialog Box is not showing up.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

I Have added the Permission in Manifest Files too. Same Scenario for Receive Boot Complete Permission. However, the Call_Phone Permission works Perfectly. Cannot identify the issue.
Android Studio TargetAPI 23 and MinAPI is 15.

Comment: @MikeM. The Target Version SDK is set at 23 in build.gradle. Only the Phone Call Permission Dialog shows up, and rest does not.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that you mentioned that `CALL_PHONE` works. Can you send SMS? I mean, do you actually get the permission? Btw, `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` isn't a dangerous permission, so it doesn't need to be requested at runtime.

Comment: No, I cannot send the SMS. The control enters the else part and just moves on without showing.

Comment: @SoumyadeepGhosh in which tag you added above permissions?

Comment: Which class does `TrustedContacts` extend?

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure all of the permissions are outside of the `<application>` tags? And you've spelled everything exactly correct in the `SEND_SMS` element? You might try cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have taken some `DANGEROUS PERMISSION` in your application which is crucial for user’s perspective that may cause privacy issue like (SEND SMS, READ CONTACTS) then **in marshmallow** only taking permission in the MANIFEST will never be enough. You have to take user’s permission in the run time(in JAVA) only when the application is going to execute the specific feature.

Application permission in run time will only work in android OS 6 (Marshmallow) and above.

Add Permission to Manifest.java

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Try my code

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 100;

//this is the onclick listener of send button
public void send(View view) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rl), "You need to grant SEND SMS permission to send sms",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                    }
                }).show();
            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            }
        } else {
            sendSMS();
        }
    } else {
        sendSMS();
    }
}

private void sendSMS() {
    String phoneNumber = "1234";
    String msg="hello, this is a text message";
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, msg, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rl), "Permission Granted",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sendSMS();

    } else {

        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rl), "Permission denied",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**To prompt user to grant or deny the permission**, you can write the following code and it will automatically show a dialog to the user and give him/her the option to allow or deny. please mark that this dialog is system defined and uneditable.

`requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);`

**Output** will be like

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this works for you..as it works in my app.

Comment: How does this answer the question at all? The OP is asking about the Marshmallow permissions dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Permission dialog will show only if your device is running `Andorid OS 6.0` or greater other no dialog will be shown but got the permission without dialog in perivous versions.

Comment: The OP states in the title that they're on 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I got my Solution. I actually wrote the Permission within application rather than outside the application in Manifest. Sorry :P

Comment: Good, but can you up vote or accept my answer too. :)